# Knight's Tour Question

Tags: combinatorics, probability, knight-moves

A chessboard is an 8 × 8 grid. A knight can move up two squares plus one square to the left or right, or up one plus two squares to the left or right. For a knight in the position shown, determine the number of paths to the top of the board, moving upward at all times. Describe how you solved the problem.

The Knight is located:

```
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . X .
```